# How to load webview with post parameters in windows 8?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, microsoft-metro

I need to load website using webview in metro apps. I could post login parameters using following method. how to load the same in webview??????

```
      string post_data = "userName=test123&password=test@321";

        // this is where we will send it
        string uri = "http://tesproject.com";

        // create a request
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        request.Method = "POST";

        // turn our request string into a byte stream
        byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(post_data);

        // this is important - make sure you specify type this way
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        Stream requestStream = await request.GetRequestStreamAsync();

        // now send it
        requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);

        // grab te response and print it out to the console along with the status code
        WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
```

Answer (score 3):

WebView class doesn't support navigating to an URL with POST parameters directly.

You could however use your code and the WebResponse to get the HTML. And then use the NavigateToString method of the WebView class to render the HTML:

```
            HttpWebResponse httpResponse= (HttpWebResponse)response;
            StreamReader reader=new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
            string htmlString= reader.ReadToEnd();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlString))
                webView.NavigateToString(htmlString);
```

Or you could create your own HTML with a form with your post values and some javascript to submit the form, but that might be a bit more cumbersome.

Comment: That is ok...I'm getting htmlstring from the response.But it is loaded in webview without any style or images. I think its baseurl issue. But dony know how to resolve it?? Any help would be appreciated.!!!!!!!