# WebView NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage Post is not delivered to the webserver

Tags: c#, post, webview, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

This is a follow-up question to the suggestion of user @Kiewic to make a post request using a webview: [Post data with a request in a Windows Store app WebView - using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646608/post-data-with-a-request-in-a-windows-store-app-webview-using-c-sharp)

So I am using this code

```
// defined before: string uri, User user
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(uri));

request.Content = new HttpStringContent(
    String.Format(
        "language={0}&session_id={1}&user_id={2}",
        Text.GetLanguage(),
        user.session_id,
        user.user_id.ToString()
    ),
    Windows.Storage.Streams.UnicodeEncoding.Utf8,
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
);

webView.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage(request); // webView defined in xaml
```

Fiddler shows me this request:

```
POST http://mobile.mysite.com/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,de-CH;q=0.5,de;q=0.3
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; Trident/7.0; Touch; SMJB; WebView/2.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: mobile.mysyte.com
Content-Length: 101
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cookie: _ga=GA1.2.769009833.1387593479; PHPSESSID=nk6b04rb7d7vu4vmm2ish7l0o4

language=en&session_id=fhihferihguiegierewfrefghxrfer&user_id=1
```

The webserver technology is PHP, so I used this code to print the post content

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

But the result is an empty array. So where is my mistake?

Comment: http://classpattern.com/posting-data-to-the-web-from-windows-phone-7.html#.UrW9ovQW2xg may be this can help

Comment: It is Windows 8.1 (not phone), so I am not sure if this helps...

Comment: It seems the request is missing a `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. But not sure how to set it :(

Comment: I have added in the first post how to set the content type. However, according to MS there is a bug with the setter function!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to a Microsoft employee there is a bug with setting the headers of the request content. This should mean that nothing is wrong with my code in the first post:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/7deaf4ba-611f-4957-af3c-9b2b2e1e1b8b/webviewnavigatewithhttprequestmessage-set-contenttype?forum=winappswithcsharp

This means you cannot really use NavigateWithHttpRequest and you should use another approach to post data. User @Kiewic made a suggestion which works on Windows 8 too:
[Post data with a request in a Windows Store app WebView - using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646608/post-data-with-a-request-in-a-windows-store-app-webview-using-c-sharp)