# Post request in web view windows phone - using C#

Tags: c#, post, webview, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to achieve the same thing, but I am getting exception when I call the InvokeScript method, Please help. I used this link ([Post data with a request in a Windows Store app WebView - using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646608/post-data-with-a-request-in-a-windows-store-app-webview-using-c-sharp)) to code, Here is my JV

```
     webview.NavigateToString(@"<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function doSomething(userIdValue, sessionIdValue) 
            { 
                document.getElementById('Username').value = userIdValue;
                document.getElementById('Password').value = sessionIdValue;
                document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
                return 'Hello World!'; 
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id='myForm' action='http://integr-dev-ma.test.plano/myplano/Account/Login' method='post'>
            <input type='hidden' id='ext-element-18' name='Username' />
            <input type='hidden' id='ext-element-24' name='Password' />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>");
```

When I call this script I get following Exception

```
 private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
            try
            {

                await webview.InvokeScriptAsync("doSomething", new string[] { "30001", "12345" });


            }
            catch (Exception aex)
            {
                string messages = "";

                messages += aex.Message + "\r\n";
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(messages);

            }
```

[image]

I resolved above problem, there was problem in Javascript, The ID was written wrong in following code

```
document.getElementById('Username').value = userIdValue;
 document.getElementById('Password').value = sessionIdValue;
```

The Username and Password should have been "ext-element-18" and "ext-element-18". Correcting javascript removed the exception. Now the basic aim of this request was to login in the webview.

My other team has developed the webpart, they have used sanchatouch framework so in the HTML code of login page there are no `<form>` tags so submitting this didn't work. I was not logged in, I am posting source of the login page, may be someone can help on this. When the user clicks on login button normally loginfunction is called, you can locate in code but anyhow I need to do post request to automate login

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!-- General Meta things -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Login -  myplano</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


    <!--<link href="/myplano/Content/Stylesheets/myplano.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/myplano/Scripts/Sencha/resources/css/sencha-touch.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
-->
    <link href="/myplano/Scripts/Sencha/resources/css/cupertino.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link href="/myplano/Content/Stylesheets/myplano.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



    <!-- Apple Meta things -->
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="white-translucent" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/myplano/Content/Images/App_Icons/Apple/myplano144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/myplano/Content/Images/App_Icons/Apple/myplano57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/myplano/Content/Images/App_Icons/Apple/myplano72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/myplano/Content/Images/App_Icons/Apple/myplano114.png">

    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/myplano/Content/Images/App_Icons/Apple/apple_startup.png">
    <!-- Android Meta things -->
    <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#384093">
    <link rel="icon" sizes=”192×192″ href="/myplano/Content/Images/App_Icons/Android/myplano192.png">

    <!-- Windows meta things -->
    <!-- TODO: Icon size needs to be 310x310 -->
    <meta name="application-name" content="myplano" />
    <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#384093" />
    <meta name="msapplication-square70x70logo" content="/myplano/Content/Images/App_Icons/Windows/tiny.png" />
    <meta name="msapplication-square150x150logo" content="/myplano/Content/Images/App_Icons/Windows/square.png" />
    <meta name="msapplication-wide310x150logo" content="/myplano/Content/Images/App_Icons/Windows/wide.png" />
    <meta name="msapplication-square310x310logo" content="/myplano/Content/Images/App_Icons/Windows/large.png" />


    <meta name='msapplication-navbutton-color' content='#384093' />
    <meta name='msapplication-tooltip' content='start myplano' />
    <meta name="msapplication-window" content="width=800;height=1024;" />
    <!--<meta name='msapplication-starturl' content='http//domain.de' />-->

    <!-- This script is required for the swipe calendar-->
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="/myplano/Scripts/myplano/momentjs/moment.js"></script>
        -->
</head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var baseUrl = "/myplano/";
        </script>

        <script src="/myplano/Scripts/Sencha/sencha-touch-all.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/Sencha/src/ux/picker/DateTime.js"></script>

<script src="/myplano/Scripts/Resources/Resource-de.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">

            Ext.Date.defaultDateFormat = "d.m.Y";
            Ext.Date.defaultTimeFormat = "H:i";
            Ext.Date.defaultTimeHMSFormat = "H:i:s";
            Ext.Date.defaultFullDateTimeFormat = "d.m.Y H:i:s";
var localLanguage = 'en';
        </script>

        <script src="/myplano/Scripts/myplano/momentjs/moment.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/Controls/Timefield.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/Controls/DateTimePicker.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/myplano/Base.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/myplano/MainMenu.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/myplano/Views/AccountValues.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/myplano/Views/Profile.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/myplano/Views/RequestList.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/myplano/Views/TimeStamps.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/myplano/Views/Calendars/DayCalendar.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/myplano/Views/Calendars/MonthCalendar.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/myplano/Views/Calendars/WeekCalendar.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/myplano/Views/Calendars/GroupCalendar.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/myplano/Views/Calendars/Calendar_Shared.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/myplano/Views/Requests/FullDay.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/myplano/Views/Requests/RequestTypeList.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/myplano/Views/Requests/NewRequest.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/myplano/Views/ApproverList.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/myplano/placeholder.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/myplano/util/PaintMonitor.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/myplano/util/SizeMonitor.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/myplano/shared.js"></script>
<script src="/myplano/Scripts/myplano/TransponderUi.js"></script>


        <div>



<script type="text/javascript">

    var userTextfield = new String;

    Ext.setup({

        onReady: function () {
            // create local user model
            Ext.define('LocalUser', {
                extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
                config: {
                    fields: [
                        { name: "id" },
                        { name: "username", type: "string" },
                        { name: "firstname", type: "string" },
                        { name: "lastname", type: "string" },
                        { name: "globalmessage", type: "string" },
                        { name: "employeemessage", type: "string" }
                    ],
                    proxy: {
                        type: 'localstorage',
                        id: 'local-user'
                    }
                }
            });
            var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                model: 'LocalUser'
            });
            store.load();
            var storageCount = store.getAllCount();
            if (storageCount > 0) {
                //console.log(storageCount + " users found");
                var userObject = store.getAt(storageCount - 1);
                var user = userObject.get("username");
                userTextfield = user;
                //console.log("last logged in user was: " + userTextfield);
            }

            //login
            var login = function () {
                var label = form.down("[itemId='signInFailedLabel']");
                var btn = form.down("button");
                label.hide();
                btn.setDisabled(true);
                form.setDisabled(true);
                btn.setText(plano.myplano.Resources.Get("LogingIn"));

                //login
                Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: plano.Base.ResolveUrl('~/Account/Login'),
                    method: 'POST',
                    params: form.getValues(),
                    success: function (response) {
                        var data = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
                        if (data.error) {
                            label.setHtml(data.error);
                            label.show();

                            form.setValues({
                                Username: "",
                                Password: ""
                            });

                            btn.setText(plano.myplano.Resources.Get("LoginDescription"));
                            btn.setDisabled(false);
                            form.setDisabled(false);
                        }
                        else if (data.success) {
                            var firstName = "";
                            var lastName = "";
                            var globalMessage = "";
                            var employeeMessage = "";

                            //if new password needed
                            if (data.newPasswordNeeded)
                            {
                                location.href = plano.Base.ResolveUrl('~/Account/ResetPassword');
                            };
                            Ext.Ajax.request({
                                url: plano.Base.ResolveUrl("~/Home/getEmployeeName"),
                                success: function (result) {


                                    var resultData = Ext.decode(result.responseText);

                                    console.log(resultData);

                                    console.log("Employee Name");
                                    console.log(resultData.data['FirstName'] + " " + resultData.data['LastName']);

                                    firstName = resultData.data['FirstName'];
                                    lastName = resultData.data['LastName'];

                                    //Store Username
                                    var thisuser = form.down("textfield").getValue();


                                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                                        url: plano.Base.ResolveUrl("~/Home/getWelcomeText"),
                                        success: function (result2)
                                        {
                                            var resultData2 = Ext.decode(result2.responseText);

                                            console.log("WelcomeText");
                                            console.log(resultData2['employeeMessage']);

                                            globalMessage = resultData2['globalMessage'];

                                            if (resultData2['employeeMessage'])
                                            {
                                                employeeMessage = resultData2['employeeMessage'];
                                            }

                                            var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                                                model: "LocalUser"
                                            });
                                            store.load();
                                            store.getProxy().clear();
                                            store.data.clear();
                                            store.add({
                                                username: thisuser,
                                                firstname: firstName,
                                                lastname: lastName,
                                                globalmessage: globalMessage,
                                                employeemessage: employeeMessage
                                            });
                                            store.sync();

                                            location.href = plano.Base.ResolveUrl('~/');

                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                            });


                        }
                    },
                    error: function (errorResponse) {
                        Ext.Msg.alert('Error', 'Login request failed');
                    }
                });
            };

            var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
                fullscreen: true,
                id: 'loginForm',
                scrollable: null,
                baseCls: 'login-form',
                config: {
                    //scrollable: false
                },
                layout: {
                    type: 'vbox',
                    pack: 'center',
                    align: 'center'
                },
                items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    hideAnimation: 'fadeOut',
                    showAnimation: 'fadeIn',
                    itemId: 'myplanoLogo',
                    html: '<img id="logo" class="login-myplano-logo" src="/myplano/Content/Images/Vector/myplano.svg" />' //~/Content/Images/myplano 256x256.png
                }, {
                    xtype: 'fieldset',
                    baseCls: 'login-form',
                    //title: plano.myplano.Resources.Get("LoginTitle"),
                    defaults: {
                        margin: '5px 0',
                        listeners: {
                            action: login
                        }
                    },
                    items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'panel',
                                html: '<div class="separator-login"></div>'
                            },
                            {
                                xtype: "textfield",
                                clearIcon: false,
                                baseCls: 'login-form',
                                placeHolder: plano.myplano.Resources.Get("UserName"),
                                value: userTextfield,
                                name: "Username",
                                required: true
                            }, {
                                xtype: "passwordfield",
                                clearIcon: false,
                                baseCls: 'login-form',
                                placeHolder: plano.myplano.Resources.Get("Password"),
                                name: "Password",
                                required: true
                            }, {
                                xtype: 'button',
                                cls: 'login-button',
                                labelCls: 'x-button-label login-button-label',
                                text: plano.myplano.Resources.Get("LoginDescription"),
                                margin: '5px auto',
                                handler: login
                            }]
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'label',
                        itemId: 'signInFailedLabel',
                        hidden: true,
                        //hideAnimation: 'fadeOut',
                        //showAnimation: 'fadeIn',
                        style: 'color: #FF8888; text-align: center;',
                        margin: "6 12 6 12"
                    }, {
                        xtype: 'label',
                        itemId: 'vernsionInfo',
                        docked: 'bottom',
                        style: 'text-align: center; color:#FFF; font-size: 0.5em;',
                        margin: "0 0 5px 0",
                        html:
                            'myplano' +
                            ' Version 1' + '.' +
                        '2' +
                        ' Rev. 73666'
                    }, {
                    xtype: 'panel',
                    docked: 'bottom',
                    itemId: 'planoLogo',
                    //hideAnimation: 'fadeOut',
                    //showAnimation: 'fadeIn',
                    //margin: '5% 0 0 0',
                    html: '<img id="logo" class="login-plano-logo" src="/myplano/Content/Images/Vector/plano_logo_white.svg" />' //~/Content/Images/myplano 256x256.png
                }]
            });

            //hide image if soft keyboard is shown
            var myplanoLogo = form.down("[itemId='myplanoLogo']");
            var planoLogo = form.down("[itemId='planoLogo']");
            window.onresize = function () {
                // If the current active element is a text input, we can assume the soft keyboard is visible.
                var windowWidth = Ext.getBody().getWidth(true);
                var windowHeight = Ext.getBody().getHeight(true);

                if (windowWidth < windowHeight)
                {
                    //keyboard is shown
                    console.log("keyboard on");
                    myplanoLogo.show();
                    planoLogo.show();
                } else {
                    //keyboard is hidden
                    console.log("keyboard off");
                    myplanoLogo.hide();
                    planoLogo.hide();
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
        </div>

        <script src="/myplano/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
<script>
    //back button disabled
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", Ext.bind(onBackKeyDown, this), false);

    function onBackKeyDown(eve)
    {

        eve.preventDefault();

        //do something
        alert('back button pressed');

    }
    //this script checks if user is idling

    var timeoutInMinutes = "20";

    //console.log("timeout in " + timeoutInMinutes + " minutes.")

    var IDLE_TIMEOUT = timeoutInMinutes*60; //seconds
    var _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
    var deviceType = "";
    document.onclick = function () {
        _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
    };
    //document.onmousemove = function () {
    //    _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
    //};
    document.onkeypress = function () {
        _idleSecondsCounter = 0;
    };
    window.setInterval(CheckIdleTime, 1000);

    function CheckIdleTime()
    {
        // create local user model
        Ext.define('LocalUser', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            config: {
                fields: [
                    { name: "id" },
                    { name: "username", type: "string" },
                    { name: "firstname", type: "string" },
                    { name: "lastname", type: "string" },
                    { name: "globalmessage", type: "string" },
                    { name: "employeemessage", type: "string" },
                    { name: "devicetype", type: "string" }
                ],
                proxy: {
                    type: 'localstorage',
                    id: 'local-user'
                }
            }
        });
        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'LocalUser'
        });
        store.load();
        var storageCount = store.getAllCount();
        if (storageCount > 0)
        {
            //console.log(storageCount + " users found");
            var userObject = store.getAt(storageCount - 1);
            deviceType = userObject.get("devicetype");
            //console.log("device type found by shared: " + deviceType);

        }
        _idleSecondsCounter++;
        var oPanel = document.getElementById("SecondsUntilExpire");
        if (oPanel)
            oPanel.innerHTML = (IDLE_TIMEOUT - _idleSecondsCounter) + "";
        if (_idleSecondsCounter >= IDLE_TIMEOUT)
        {
            if (deviceType == "terminal")
            {
                location.href = plano.Base.ResolveUrl('~/Account/TerminalLogout');
            } else
            {
                location.href = plano.Base.ResolveUrl('~/Account/Logout');
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: You can use Google Chrome to see the website, then right click on the button that submits the form and select **Inspect**, there you should see the ID of the button you need to do submit on.

Comment: You mean Id of form tag should be same as id of button on that webpage ?
If yes then its not woking my button id is ext-button-1

 
    <body>
        <form id='ext-button-1' action='http://www.***.com'>
            <input type='hidden' id='ext-element-18' name='Username' />
            <input type='hidden' id='ext-element-24' name='Password' />
        </form>
    </body>